# Problem with Volume

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

A bug probably.

This should give the volume of the unit sphere:

```
vol = Volume[{1. r, th, ph}, {r, 0, 1}, {th, 0, Pi}, {ph, -Pi, Pi}, "Spherical"]
```

but it gives:

> ```
> NIntegrate[1. Sqrt[r^4 Sin[th]^2], {{r, 0, 1}, {th, 0, π}, {ph, -π, π}}]
> ```

Here is a workaround:

```
MapAt[Sequence @@ # &, vol, {-1}]
```

> 4.18879

that is 4./3 Pi

Can this be confirmed?

Version: 10.0.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem with 10.3.1

Comment: Sincerely, I will not upvote answers, except if they afford something very new.

Comment: I get the `NIntegrate` results, along with an error, "NIntegrate::write: Tag List in {r,0,1} is Protected. >>", in 10.0.2 for Mac OS.  Fixed in 10.1 (Mac OS, of course).  I'd say it's a bug that's been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I get on OS X 10.3.1  (64bit)

```
vol = Volume[{1. r, th, ph}, {r, 0, 1}, {th, 0, Pi}, {ph, -Pi, Pi}, 
  "Spherical"]
```

> 4.18879